# Selecting rows with reference id's to same table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table call user such as below:

```
id  name  ref_id  
--  ----  ------  
1   Sam   0      
2   Jack  1       
3   Sue   2       
4   Sam2  1       
5   Sue2  3       
6   Sam3  1 
7   Alan  3       
8   Tom   3
9   Lyn   2
10  Van   1
```

I want to select the user have referred 3 people. 
Is it possible to write a query and select this:

```
Name
-- 
Sam
Sue
```

Comment: You can try with self join

Comment: Why do some users have their name as (for example) 'Sam', 'Sam2', 'Sam3'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use self join like below

```
SELECT a.`name`  FROM ref a LEFT JOIN ref b 
ON a.id = b.ref_id 
GROUP BY a.name 
HAVING COUNT(b.id) >2
```

Try this [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11fd9/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use query below:

```
    select Count(u1.name) unit,u1.name from ref as u1 INNER JOIN ref as u2 ON u1.Id = u2.ref_id
    group By u1.id
    having unit > 3
```

you can replace unit > 3 to unit > 2